# Turns off when touching test points

Tags: power

my pi was running fine and then I tried plugging in an alfa wifi adapter into it, and SSH stopped responding so I assume it had crashed, then it wouldn't fully boot and gave an error (Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init). So, I decided to test it with a multimeter, but as soon as I touch TP1 and TP2, the PWR LED goes out and it shuts off and my meter reads 0, as soon as I remove the needles from the test points, the board powers back on. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the power is being shorted out

Perhaps your meter is on the wrong setting. It should be on DC Volts

If you meter has separate jacks for current, make sure you have the leads plugged into the correct jacks. Usually the red would be the right most and the black would be the one next to it (common)

If you could tell us the meter model or add a picture, it might help get a better answer.

Many USB devices have too much capacitance on board to be hot plugged into the RPi. The Supply voltage will drop momentarily as the device is plugged in, and that is enough for bad things to happen.

Answer (score 0):

By plugging wifi adapter you most probably overloaded your power supply.

Please, check the rating of your power adapter, should be 5V / 2A or more.